# How to modify ggplot2 stat_density_2d contour plot density scaling?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, contour, stat-density2d

I'm working with a two column table that I am trying to make a density contour plot out of. "HiChIP_VillusvsCrypt" is the x axis and "RNAseq_VillusvsCrypt" is the y axis. 
[If you see in this attached image, there is a legend with the density scaling from 0 to 0.2. I would like to be able to play around with this scaling, if possible (i.e. set bounds between 0 and 0.1).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQRZi.jpg) I appreciate any advice!

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(HNF4_Looping_HiChIPvsRNASeq_VillusvsCrypt$HiChIP_log2FC_VillusvsCrypt, HNF4_Looping_HiChIPvsRNASeq_VillusvsCrypt$RNAseq_log2FC_VillusvsCrypt)
ggplot(df1, aes(df$HNF4_Looping_HiChIPvsRNASeq_VillusvsCrypt.HiChIP_log2FC_VillusvsCrypt, df$HNF4_Looping_HiChIPvsRNASeq_VillusvsCrypt.RNAseq_log2FC_VillusvsCrypt))+                       
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level.. ), geom = "polygon")+scale_x_continuous(name="HiChIP_VillusvsCrypt", limits=c(-4,4))+scale_y_continuous(name="RNASeq_VillusvsCrypt", limits=c(-4,4))
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your example code, so I'll substitute with a standard dataset to illustrate my points.

Playing with the bounds simply setting the limits on a colour/fill and making sure the `oob` argument is appropriate.

Let's say we have the following plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

myplot <- ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(level)),
                  geom = "polygon") +
  xlim(1, 6) +
  ylim(35, 100)
myplot
```

[image]

We can play around with the limits as follows:

```r
myplot + scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.01), 
                               oob = scales::squish)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want to set a multiplier on the underlying values, you can use the `aes()` function as follows:

```
aes(fill = after_stat(level * 10))
```

Note that the `after_stat()` function requires ggplot2 v3.3.0. Earlier versions use `stat()` or even older syntax is to use `..myvariable..`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was very helpful!